# update 3 columns in 1 uppdate

Tags: sql

I'm writing a query to update a table. The table has many fields among which there are 3 fields: column1, column2, column3 each of which can be null.
The data is loaded every day. On day 1 a row can come in which
column1 is null,
column2 is not null
column3 is null.
The next day there may be a row where
column1 is not null,
column2 is null,
column3 is null.
The idea is to insert new rows, and those rows which are identical to previously uploaded ones, but which column1, column2, column3 change are not inserted, but updated.
I tried to write a query to update all three fields at once. But in case described above, I will change not null to null.
Does anyone know a way to update any of the fields in a single update query without writing null there?

for example:

```
update table2 upt
set column1 = n.column1,
    column2 = n.column2,
    column3 = n.column3
from (select new.column1, new.column2, new.column3, new.column4, new.column5
      from table1 new
      where new.column4 in (select old.column4 from table2 old
                            where old.column5 = new.column5
                            and (old.column1 is null or old.column2 is null or old.column3 is null)
      and (new.column1 is not null or new.column2 is not null and new.column3 is not null) n
where upt.date_fielad = '2022-01-01'
and upt.column4 = n.column4
and upt.column5 = n.column5
and (upt.column1 <> n.column1
     or upt.column2 <> n.column2
     or upt.column3 <> n.column3)
```

How I can change this query to not update not null fields null?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: It's not clear which database you are using, and the answer depends on it. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSql

Comment: You use the `coalesce(...) function with existing values such that if the new value is null then existing value is 'retained' and if the new value is not null the column is updated`. So perhaps `set column1 = coalesce(n.column1, upt.column1)` and the same on the other columns.  Also you may want to eliminate the predicate `and upt.column1 <> n.column1 ...` since if *ANY* of those columns are null the result is NULL and therefore the  row would not be updated. Or at least explain what you think that predicate does.